# Line break not working as expected

Tags: php, html, line-breaks

I'm using an API to display information about users.

When I try to implement a line break for presentation purposes, so as to have an information displayed below another, it fails to work and I can't seem to identify the reason for that unexpected behaviour.

Below is the image:

[image]

As you can see, both **ID** and **Group** are is displayed on the same line.

Here is my code:

```
<td>ID:</td><td><strong /> ' . $data['response']['id'] . '</td><br/>
<td>Group:</td><td><strong />' . $data['response']['groupName'];</td>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use break? If you are using `td`, you are making a table. You use `<tr>` (i.e. rows) for breaking.

Comment: Instead of a `<br>` try starting a new row with `<tr>`.

Comment: You can't have anything in a `<tr>` that isn't inside `<td>` or `<th>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a table.  If you want the `br` to put the text on the next line, the text needs to be in the same table cell.  Change your markup to:

```
<td>ID:<strong /> ' . $data['response']['id'] . '<br/>Group:<strong />' . $data['response']['groupName']</td>;
```

Or you could not use a br at all and just add a new table row:

```
<tr><td>ID:</td><td><strong /> ' . $data['response']['id'] . '</td></tr>
<tr><td>Group:</td><td><strong />' . $data['response']['groupName'].'</td></tr>';
```

Comment: hi that worked thanks, also i'm having issues trying to display the image from the api to the image box how can i display it with src? the name is avatar

Comment: I can't tell without seeing the code, but you should just be able to append the location in the html.  Though you will want to make sure that the paths are correct.  One other thing, you should be careful when generating html in this manner is that it is possible for XSS attacks to be made on your page.  You should escape/encode the data to prevent malicious html/js from appearing on your page.

Comment: The xss would come from the group or image source that you are using.  For example if `$data['response']['groupName']` was `<script>alert("xss attack");</script>` the javascript will be executed allowing someone access to your user's browser.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29

Comment: but im using ssl. cloudflare, and soon drupal don't they use protection again'st xss? so how could i display the image securely?

Comment: When you are appending text into html by text concatenation, you want to make sure that any html in the strings does not get rendered to the page.  I was just trying to caution you in this regard as I have no idea where you are getting the text from so I can't say anything beyond that.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133389/discussion-between-bob-marley-and-schleis